# Firefox/IE handling css "right" property differently?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have a div like this...

```
<div style="position:fixed; top: 60px; right: -51px;">
      <form>
         ....
      </form>
  </div>
```

In Chrome/Safari, it perfectly positions a little search box at the top right of the screen.

In firefox/IE, the top is correct, but the position to the right isn't tight enough to the edge (looks like around 100px).

Here's an example: http://codepen.io/d3wannabe/pen/LZNVqe

Hugely appreciate any thoughts from anyone who knows why this might be happening!

Comment: I've just looked at your codepen in Chrome, Edge, Firefox and IE11 and the search box is positioned in the same place for all of them on my laptop - just looked again and perhaps it is a few pxiel different

Comment: Hey HenryM - I just changed the right position to -70px.  To me it's a very clear difference now - pretty tight on chrome, and quite a way off on firefox.  Please let me know if you still don't see a noticeable difference and I'll upload screenshots (p.s. either way, any ideas on the cause of the difference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about the `right`, but about width of `.search-container` — it is different in Chrome and Firefox, thus it appears like `.search-box` have different right gap across browsers (Firefox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hupX.png). You can use developer tools to inspect that in different browsers. If you want to have equal right gap you have to normalize content width within `position: fixed` div.

Comment: thanks Andrey - you're right that if, for example, I specify width: 100px on search-container, it will anchor the the image.  The only problem I need to figure out now is how to do that without breaking the form (i.e. try clicking on it when the search-container has a 100px width).  Any further thoughts on that?  If not, I guess I'll accept this as the answer to the question since it addresses the general point about anchoring to the right

Answer (score 1):

adding `width:0px;` and changing to `right:0px` seems to work?

Comment: for me that just breaks the form (although I see what you mean that the search-icon itself is at least anchored to the right - but the rest of it is completely off the page)

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks.